# Return average array for each element of list of arrays with columns and rows of fixed shape

Tags: arrays, numpy, average

I have got multiple arrays with 1000 rows and 500 columns and I want to return an array which takes each element (row i and column j) of the arrays and calculates its average.

I have tried the following:

```py
listofarrays=[array1,array2,array3,array4,...,arrayx]
lst1=[]
newavgarray=[]

n=1000
m=500

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,m):
        for h in range(0,len(listofarrays)):
            arraynumber=listofarrays[h]
            lst1=backgroundnumber[i,j].append
        avg=lst1.mean()
        newavgarray=avg.append()
print(newavgarray)
```

Comment: `sum(listofarrays)/len(listofarrays)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can review here : average of matrix

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.mean.html